# Insert/update a flag depending on values matched between to tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to make a procedure where:

1. If an `ID` exists in `table B` but not in `Table A` code with be inser/updated to 0.
2. Else if the `ID` exists in both table code field will be insert/updated to 1.

I have two tables, for example:

```
Table A      Table B
+----+--+--+----+------+
| ID |  |  | Id | Code |
+----+--+--+----+------+
|  1 |  |  |  1 |    0 |
|  2 |  |  |  2 |    0 |
|  3 |  |  |  3 |    0 |
|  4 |  |  |  4 |    0 |
|    |  |  |  5 |    0 |
|    |  |  |  6 |    0 |
+----+--+--+----+------+
```

Can you please help me with that?

`Table B` in the end should be like this:

```
+----+------+
| Id | Code |
+----+------+
|  1 |    1 |
|  2 |    1 |
|  3 |    1 |
|  4 |    1 |
|  5 |    0 |
|  6 |    0 |
+----+------+
```

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: What do u mean robert?

Comment: Please do not ask us to write your code for you. Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first. Ask about specific problems with your existing implementation. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You are very kind Robet! I had a problem that tried to solve, didn't ask for you to right code, i did ask how could i solve my problem You could just have said -> "use a merge".  But thatnks a lot anyways. For my luck not all the ppl are so rude as you.

Comment: I did not mean to be rude. I provided you with a link how to ask a good question. Following these rules will give you better quality answers. 'Merge' is one possible answer to your question. There are lots more, and maybe even better, answers. Your question is just to broad. Furthermore it is good practice to describe what you’ve already tried and the results of any research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this: make left join to generate values of `table B`, which not present in `table A`, then merge to update column `Code`.

```
merge into table_b
using (select b.id, case when a.id is null then 0 else 1 end code
         from table_b b left join table_a a on a.id = b.id) t
   on (t.id = table_b.id)
 when matched then update
  set code = t.code
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MERGE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm):

```
MERGE into tableB B
USING tableA A
ON (a.id = b.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET code = 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (id,code) values (a.id, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the answer below for your question...,

```
create table TABLEA (ID int);

insert into TABLEA (ID) values (1);
insert into TABLEA (ID) values (2);
insert into TABLEA (ID) values (3);
insert into TABLEA (ID) values (4);
insert into TABLEA (ID) values (5);

create table TABLEB (ID int, code int);

insert into TABLEB (ID,code) values (1,0);
insert into TABLEB (ID,code) values (2,0);
insert into TABLEB (ID,code) values (3,0);
insert into TABLEB (ID,code) values (4,0);
insert into TABLEB (ID,code) values (5,0);
insert into TABLEB (ID,code) values (6,0);
insert into TABLEB (ID,code) values (7,0);
insert into TABLEB (ID,code) values (8,0);

UPDATE TABLEB SET CODE=1 FROM TABLEB B INNER JOIN TABLEA as A on A.id=B.id;

SELECT * FROM TABLEB;

ID  CODE
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   1
5   1
6   0
7   0
8   0
```